# Доступ к SharedPreferences из DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Создаю окно при помощи `DialogFragment` и `layout` файла.

Вопрос в том что мне нужно получить доступ к `SharedPreferences` из класса моего диалога. Но этого я сделать не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне так сделать.

спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Доступ к `SharedPreferences` из `DialogFragment` можно получить с помощью активити:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...);
```